# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified, using: sql server stored procedure, Listview

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I have the following code for my Edit Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_EditDates] 

    @ID int,
    @PublishYear int, 
    @PublishMonth int,
    @PayDte varchar(200),
    @PublishDte varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    UPDATE PaymentAndPublishingDates SET PublishYear = @PublishYear, PublishMonth = @PublishMonth, PayDte = @PayDte, PublishDte = @PublishDte
    WHERE ID=@ID;
END
```

And the following for my Select stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RetrieveAllDates] 

AS BEGIN SELECT DISTINCT

PaymentAndPublishingDates.ID, PaymentAndPublishingDates.PublishYear,  
PaymentAndPublishingDates.PublishMonth, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR,PaymentAndPublishingDates.PayDte,106)AS PayDate,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,PaymentAndPublishingDates.PublishDte,120) AS PublishDate 

FROM  PaymentAndPublishingDates 

END
```

And I have a datasource like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Payment_Dates" 
    InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#FFF8DC;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishYearLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishYear") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishMonthLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishMonth") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PayDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PayDate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishDateLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#008A8C;color: #FFFFFF;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" 
                    Text="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Cancel" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PublishYearTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("PublishYear") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PublishMonthTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("PublishMonth") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PayDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PayDate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PublishDateTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("PublishDate") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" 
            style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    No data was returned.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                    Text="Insert" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                    Text="Clear" />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PublishYearTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("PublishYear") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PublishMonthTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("PublishMonth") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PayDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PayDate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="PublishDateTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("PublishDate") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishYearLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishYear") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishMonthLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishMonth") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PayDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PayDate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishDateLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
                        style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                            <th runat="server">
                            </th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                ID</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                PublishYear</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                PublishMonth</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                PayDate</th>
                            <th runat="server">
                                PublishDate</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" 
                    style="text-align: center;background-color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #000000;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#008A8C;font-weight: bold;color: #FFFFFF;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishYearLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishYear") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishMonthLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishMonth") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PayDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PayDate") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="PublishDateLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("PublishDate") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Payment_Dates" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TUT_ElectronicPayslipsConnectionString %>" 
    InsertCommand="sp_CapturePayDate" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    SelectCommand="sp_RetrieveAllDates" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="sp_EditDates" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishYear" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishMonth" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PayDte" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishDte" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishYear" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishMonth" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PayDte" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PublishDte" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The data displays fine but when I try to edit fields I get this error "Procedure or function sp_EditDates has too many arguments specified".

Please Help

Comment: Can you provide the code of the Select stored procedure?

Comment: @jyparask Don't you mean the Update stored proc?

Comment: yes show the code that is calling the sp/

Comment: @DGibbs Well, the Update SP is there. I need to see the Select too

Comment: This is my select stored procedure:                                                                 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RetrieveAllDates] 
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT DISTINCT 
   PaymentAndPublishingDates.ID,
   PaymentAndPublishingDates.PublishYear, PaymentAndPublishingDates.PublishMonth, CONVERT(VARCHAR,PaymentAndPublishingDates.PayDte,106)AS PayDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR,PaymentAndPublishingDates.PublishDte,120)AS PublishDate FROM PaymentAndPublishingDates
END

Comment: And i would also like to see the whole code of the ListView if there is any.

Comment: Code for the ListView is too long, I can't post as a comment

Comment: I just edited my question by adding the ListView code, please look at it. Thanks